# Build a dask dataframe from a list of dask delayed objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I have a list of dask delayed objects `Portfolio_perfs`:

```
type(Portfolio_perfs)
<class 'list'>
#print until 3
Portfolio_perfs[:3]
[Delayed('getitem-b7fd8629e2a0ecfe4e61ae6f39926140'), Delayed('getitem-af3225459229d541b73dc79319edaec2'), Delayed('getitem-0555389e6dd01031de85e293b8c42b85')]
```

Each delayed object is a numpy array of length 2

```
Portfolio_perfs[0].compute()
array([0.75620425, 0.1835988 ])
```

I want to build the following dataframe without using `dask.compute`:

```
pd.DataFrame(dask.compute(*Portfolio_perfs))
            0         1
0    0.756204  0.183599
1    0.825101  0.195705
2    0.792804  0.189422
3    0.786267  0.178194
4    0.860377  0.220204
..        ...       ...
595  0.636857  0.139955
596  0.925144  0.218462
597  0.925077  0.213963
598  0.922016  0.206081
599  0.770950  0.170273

[600 rows x 2 columns]
```

How can I build this dask dataframe without going through `dask.compute`?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each delayed object is a numpy array, you are interested in [`da.from_delayed()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.from_delayed):

```
dask_array = da.from_delayed(Portfolio_perfs)
```

Alternatively, it's possible to convert numpy arrays to pandas dataframes and then use:

```
dd.from_delayed()
```

Note that it's not possible to do it with `pd.DataFrame` because pandas will not know what to do with the delayed objects, so you will need to use `dask.dataframe` for this task.

Comment: thank you, had to modify my initial array from numpy to pandas dataframe

Comment: Ah, yes, `dask.array` also had `from_delayed` function, if you want to keep the data in array format.

Answer (score 1):

tried to use `dd.from_delayed` but had the following error

```
dd.from_delayed(Portfolios_perfs)
TypeError: Expected partition to be DataFrame, Series, or Index, got numpy.ndarray
```

had to convert my numpy array to dataframe before using `dd.from_delayed()`

```
Portfolios_perfs[0].compute()
          0         1
0  0.764544  0.176615
#
dd_final=dd.from_delayed(Portfolios_perfs)
dd_final
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                       0        1
npartitions=300
                 float64  float64
                     ...      ...
...                  ...      ...
                     ...      ...
                     ...      ...
Dask Name: from-delayed, 900 tasks
#
#
dd_final.compute()
           0         1
0   0.764544  0.176615
0   0.753957  0.176094
0   0.891951  0.180247
0   0.813954  0.180084
0   1.089214  0.260875
..       ...       ...
0   0.655544  0.138117
0   0.944792  0.233119
0   0.720967  0.157746
0   0.774837  0.181025
0   0.770270  0.165283

[300 rows x 2 columns]
```