# Concatenate Excel Files using Dask

Tags: excel, concatenation, dask

I have 20 Excel files and need to concatenate them using Dask (I have already done it using pandas, but it will grow in the future).  I have used the following solution found here:  [Reading multiple Excel files with Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68055652/reading-multiple-excel-files-with-dask)

But throws me an error:  cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

What I am assuming is that it does not create a Dataframe, tried the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

files = glob.glob(r"D:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XXX\*.xlsx")

# note we are wrapping in delayed only the function, not the arguments
delayeds = [dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(i, skiprows=0) for i in files]

# the line below launches actual computations
results = dask.compute(delayeds)

# after computation is over the results object will 
# contain a list of pandas dataframes

df = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
```

The original solution did not include df=pd.DataFrame().  Where is the mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: this code is looking perfectly correct for me. I think you are correct and some elements of results are not a dataFrame. Try printing results to check what type ob objects are

Comment: note that [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) will return a dictionary by default - you should provide an argument for `sheet_name` if you want a single DataFrame for each file. I think providing the sheet name in combination with the solution in your answer is the right approach.

Comment: however, this question is a duplicate as you note. you could post your answer as a response to the other question :)

Comment: Thank you, will do so and try your approach.  Will post you.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following solution:  [Build a dask dataframe from a list of dask delayed objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623761/build-a-dask-dataframe-from-a-list-of-dask-delayed-objects)

Realized that the last line was not using dask but pandas.  Changed the data to a numpy array to pandas.

Here is the code:

```
files = glob.glob(r"D:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XXX\*.xlsx")

# note we are wrapping in delayed only the function, not the arguments
delayeds = [dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(i, skiprows=0) for i in files]

# the line below launches actual computations
results = dask.compute(delayeds)

# after computation is over the results object will 
# contain a list of pandas dataframes
dask_array = dd.from_delayed(delayeds) # here instead of pd.concat
dask_array.compute().to_csv(r"D:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XXX\*.csv") # Please be aware of the dtypes on your Excel.
```