# Why is the CPU usage detected by the system inconsistent with the data detected by dasbboard?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am learning how to use Dask to processing multiple excel files, my code is like (mainly borrowed from [Concatenate Excel Files using Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73613688/concatenate-excel-files-using-dask)) :

```
def process_file(filename):
    file0 = pd.read_excel(path + filename)
    cleaning data
    return file0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client(n_workers=8, processes=False)  # my cpu get 4 cores 8 threads;if processes=True then it will report bugs like https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5302
    gj_path = "E:/path/to/my/files/"
    file_list = os.listdir(gj_path)
    delayeds = [dask.delayed(process_file)(i) for i in file_list]
    results = dask.compute(delayeds)
    dask_array = dd.from_delayed(delayeds)
    print(dask_array.year.value_counts().compute())  # want to check year distribution
    client.shutdown()
```

I thought that by setting n_workers to 8, all the cores of the CPU could be invoked, but the CPU usage detected by the system task manager is very different from the situation reported by the dashboard, you can see it from this pic:
[image]

so how to understand n_workers and the CPU reported in dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

The dashboard view you are looking at does *not* tell you about CPU utilisation. In deed, there are 8 tasks currently assigned, but that doesn't 8 cores' worth of work. The following are the main causes:

- many operations need to wait on external events, particularly for reading/writing data from disk or network. Such operations do not use (much) CPU, but you cannot proceed until they are done
- when you have multiple threads in a single python process, there is only a certain class of operation that can be truly parallel: those that are designed to release the "GIL". In other words, pandas/numpy code will often manage to use a full core per thread, but pure python code will often be limited to 100% of one core across all threads. Distributed allows you to change the mix of processes and threads in your cluster, depending on the workload.

Comment: thanks! but what about the CPU panel in the lower right corner, you can see there are 8 horizontal charts showing the CPU utilisation close to 100%

Comment: Hm, that was not the view I was expecting in that corner sorry - I am not sure exactly what dask is measuring there.